# editing sysinternal log to post on forum

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, process-explorer, sysinternals

I use sysinternal tool procmon
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

I want to edit its log because I want to post it online on technical forums for disucssions.
I want to remove personally identifiable information from it but microsoft word does not let me open the file. Here is a screenshot.
[500 mb word file not opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBMEA.jpg)

Comment: [How to open Gigabyte-sized text files on Windows - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/22/how-to-open-gigabyte-sized-text-files-on-windows/)

Comment: You can't open a .PML file in Word.  You can open the .pml in Process Monitor and save it back out as other formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to work in the Windows admin space and we used [gsplit](https://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit) quite a bit. It was fast, dependable and good for file splitting.